# Capture jenkins abort in java #Testng

Tags: java, jenkins, testng

I have one job in jenkins which is executing testng suite.

Testng suite has 5 test cases.

I have one class `SuiteListener.java` which implements `ISuiteListener` interface.
SuiteListener class has one overrided method `onFinish()` which triggers mail which contains success count, failure count, total count, success percentage.

If i abort jenkins job then it is not triggering mail.

Is there any way to handle jenkins abort event in java so that i can send mail which has all meaningful information.

Comment: Are you using pipelines?

Comment: I use Jenkins, TestNG & Java but also with `onTestFailure` & `onTestSkipped` overrides, neither of which get triggered on aborting the parent Jenkins job running TestNg via batch cmd. I've setup my Java test framework to update an RDBMs with live test data (pass, fail, screenshots etc) and can thus trigger my summary emails from Jenkins, pulling the test stats from the RDBMs. Rather than an RDBMs you could write you test stats to a flat file instead. So an alternative rather than a solution.

Comment: @AleksanderStelmaczonek : No

Comment: @elworthy : Thanks for your response but i am looking for different approach